# how to remove a string from arraylist of strings, ANDROID

Tags: android, string, arraylist, android-edittext

I created an arraylist of strings

```
List<String> textArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then I added the strings(which I am getting from edittext) to textArray as follows

```
String text = editText1.getText().toString();
textArray.add(text);
```

Now I created a button and need to remove the string from the array when the button is clicked.But i dont know what to do. 
I know for arrays of bitmaps we clear a bitmap from array using recycle but Please suggest me how to remove or clear the string from arraylist.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can call one of:

to remove all entries

```
textArray.clear();
```

to remove from a specific position (e.g. first item)

```
textArray.remove(0);
```

to remove a specific string (that `equals` yours)

```
textArray.remove("myString");
```

Comment: textArray.remove("myString"); not work with custom object !

Comment: The original question was about strings. So yeah it will not work on custom objects. The reason is that your custom objects are not "equal". This is more of a language thing. Check http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

Getting position from the textArray array list

```
int pos = textArray.indexOf(text);
```

and then remove from the string position

```
    textArray.remove(pos);
```

because we cannot directly remove the string. we can remove the string contains position.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with more then one way as per your need.

```
textArray.clear();
```

It will clear whole ArrayList.

If you want to remove only some specifis data from index then,

```
textArray.remove(INDEX TO REMOVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
String text = editText1.getText().toString();
textArray.add(text);
```

to remove

```
textArray.remove(text);
```